# ffmpeg transcoding in python with aws-lambda limits

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe, aws-lambda

I want to transcode audio file into HLS with segments in aws-lambda environment:

```
ffmpeg -i 2540.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_list battle.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts battle%05d.ts
```

But there are cases when I need to transcode files larger than 500 MB (disc space limit for aws-lambda).

How can I trancode audio file parts with segments? Is it possible to redirect segments to `pipe:1` `(stdout)`, and upload these segments and manifes from `stdout` to s3 in separated files?